# How to resolve a "time-travelling" bug?

Tags: android, screenshot

I'm sure there's a legit term for this, but i've run into a really awkward bug:

On Android, I'm trying to screenshot some views and then send them over by email. I've gotten the screenshot code to work just fine:

```
View screenView = activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, configuration);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
screenView.draw(canvas);
return bitmap;
```

i've taken some screenshots successfully and everything looks wonderful.

2 weeks later, here's the problem -

it turns out somehow on one of the pages in the app, some icons are not showing up. I double check to make sure that i'm not going crazy -> and sure enough, my previous screenshots all prove that the icons used to show up 2 weeks ago. So, i decide the `git checkout` my commit number 2 weeks ago, and run the code from there. that's when i ran into the "time-travelling bug". SOMEHOW, by checking out the git commit 2 weeks ago, i am seeing this new bug where icons aren't showing up on the old code (the code that used to work, with screenshots to prove it worked).

i'm totally stumped. i made sure i checked out the exact git commit that had working code 2 weeks ago, and now (2 weeks later), i see the new bug on old code.

1. how is this possible?
2. how do i even go about debugging this?

Comment: Given the source code is the same, how about the screens you try to capture? Are they exactly the same?

Comment: @henry000 the screens are not exactly the same because the screenshot is a listview of ppl's names with status icons. the names and icons are always changing. but the status icons used to appear 2 weeks ago and now they're not :'(